# How to embed Preset dashboard/charts in React/Next.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache-superset

I created a sample pie chart in a published dashboard, then I copied `<iframe />` code snippet from "Share > Embed code" and pasted in a `/test` page.

```
export default function Test() {
  return (
    <>
      <iframe
        width="600"
        height="400"
        seamless
        frameBorder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        src="https://c2e8b9ae.us2a.app.preset.io/superset/explore/p/G48PLPkAFEJ/?standalone=1&height=400"
      ></iframe>
    </>
  );
}
```

But it shows "**manage.app.preset.io refused to connect**". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not compatible with Preset Cloud, due to cross-origin restrictions: https://preset.atlassian.net/browse/PPR-191